# Delphi abstract function calls with different name than base class

Tags: delphi, unicode, abstract, backwards-compatibility

Say I've got a function

```
function GetFieldName(FieldIndex: Integer; FieldName: PChar; 
    Len: Integer): Integer; virtual; abstract;
```

and I'm trying to add

```
function GetFieldNameA(FieldIndex: Integer; FieldName: PAnsiChar; 
    Len: Integer): Integer;
```

Which will temporarily bridge my database connection for unicode.

I want to continue to call GetFieldName, make it not abstract, and do some bit typecasting to call GetFieldNameA, which will become a technically abstract version of the first GetFieldName.  (I don't want to change the base class at all)

Is there a way, like adding the 'name' keyword for external references, to have an abstract function with a different name in the subclass?

What I'm imagining ending up with is something like:

```
function GetFieldName(FieldIndex: Integer; FieldName: PChar; 
    Len: Integer): Integer; 
function GetFieldNameA(FieldIndex: Integer; FieldName: PAnsiChar;
    Len: Integer): Integer name 'GetFieldName Virtual Abstract';
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to move the current hierarchy of (overridden) implementations in GetFieldName to a hierarchy of (overridden) implementations of GetFieldNameA, without having to change the code that actually uses GetFieldName?

Comment: @marjan I'm trying to add a function GetFieldNameA (and a host of other functions) that will act the same as GetFieldName did in Delphi 7.  I want to call GetFieldName using unicode, have it to the conversion and call GetFieldNameA.  The problem is, GetFieldName is abstract, and it's implementation is in a completely different project.  This is weird old code.

Comment: if the implementation of the virtual abstract functions is in (an) other project(s), you are indeed in DS (deep shit or dire straits, depending on your preference of trouble...). You will indeed need @Rob's solution and/or make GetFieldNameA virtual abstract and rename the method in your implementation libraries. If you then code your unicode versions as GetFieldNameW in the libraries, you can at least keep the decision which one to call in GetFieldName in your base class (it's sort of taking a leaf out of the Windows API cookbook and Delphi's external declarations).

Comment: @Marjan, that's what I'm going to do, at least there is a way out without modifying every call to the functions (I'm doing everything in my power to avoid a fullscale string -> ansistring conversion) - and, the base class only has a few subclasses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do what you're proposing.

Instead, override `GetFieldName`. Have it convert the `PChar` to a `PAnsiChar` (if necessary) before calling `GetFieldNameA`. The latter doesn't have to be (and can't, actually) be marked `override`. It can be an ordinary non-virtual function.

The unfortunate part of that suggestion is that you'd have to do it in *every* descendant class. The alternative is to add a virtual abstract `GetFieldNameA` to the base class and then change all the descendants to override that instead of `GetFieldName`. Change `GetFieldName` in the base class to call `GetFieldNameA`. But that's a non-starter if you can't change the base class.

Comment: I totally messed up my question, but this is appears to be the right answer.

Comment: Therefore, I don't think I'm going to be able to escape this without massive mods. Crap.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you can trick Delphi by injecting replaced base class.

If the class that declares original GetFieldName is called TClass1 declared in Unit1(pas or dcu), then:

- make a new unit (TrickUnit.pas).
- In the TrickUnit.pas add unit of the old class in the uses section (TrickUnit.pas uses Unit1)
- In the TrickUnit.pas declare the class with the same name as the original class, and make it inherit the original class `type TClass1 = class(Unit1.TClass1)`
- override GetFieldName and add your custom implementation.
- Just add TrickClass.pas **at the end** of uses section (interface part) of each unit that expects original class

As long as TrickUnit.pas is at the end of uses section, all of your descendants will end up inheriting your replaced class with no code changes other than adding `using ......, TrickUnit`